# Multiple separate IF conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have multiple `IF` statements that are independent of each other in my stored procedure. But for some reason they are being nested inside each other as if they are part of one big if statement

```
ELSE IF(SOMETHNGZ)
 BEGIN
  IF(SOMETHINGY)
   BEGIN..END
  ELSE IF (SOMETHINGY)
   BEGIN..END
  ELSE
   BEGIN..END
  --The above works I then insert this below and these if statement become nested----
  IF(@A!= @SA)

  IF(@S!= @SS)

  IF(@C!= @SC) 

  IF(@W!= @SW)
  --Inserted if statement stop here
 END
ELSE <-- final else
```

So it will be treated like this

```
IF(@A!= @SA){           
        IF(@S!= @SS){           
            IF(@C!= @SC) {      
                IF(@W!= @SW){}
            }
        }
    }
```

What I expect is this

```
IF(@A!= @SA){}          
IF(@S!= @SS){}      
IF(@C!= @SC){}
IF(@W!= @SW){}
```

I have also tried this and it throws `Incorrect syntax near "ELSE". Expecting "CONVERSATION"`

```
IF(@A!= @SA)
BEGIN..END                  
IF(@S!= @SS)
BEGIN..END      
IF(@C!= @SC) 
BEGIN..END  
IF(@W!= @SW)
   BEGIN..END
```

Note that from `ELSE <--final else` down is now nested inside  `IF(@W!= @SW)` Even though it is part of the outer if statement `ELSE IF(SOMETHNGZ)` before.

**EDIT**

As per request my full statement

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_PLaces]  
@ID int, 
..more params
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @SomeId INT
..more varaible
SET @SomeId = user define function()
..more SETS
IF(@ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO Places              
    VAlUES(..Values...)            
    ... more stuff...               
    BEGIN TRY       
        exec Store procedure 
            @FIELD = 15, ... more params...             
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
        RETURN -1
    END CATCH                      
    RETURN 0                
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
    RETURN -1
END CATCH   
END 
ELSE IF(@ID IS NOT NULL AND @ID in (SELECT ID FROM Places)) 
BEGIN   
     SELECT @MyName = Name ...  
    ...Some stuff....                       
    IF(SOMETHNG_1)          
        BEGIN TRY               
            UPDATE ....                                                                 
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
            RETURN -1
        END CATCH
    ELSE IF(SOMETHNG_2)
        BEGIN TRY
            UPDATE ...                                                      
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
            RETURN -1
        END CATCH   
    ELSE  
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRY
                UPDATE ...                                                              
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
                RETURN -1
            END CATCH   
        END             
      --The above works I then insert this below and these if statement become nested----
  IF(@A!= @SA)
    BEGIN
     exec Stored procedure 
            @FIELD = 15,
            ... more params...
    END                 
IF(@S!= @SS)
  BEGIN
     exec Stored procedure 
            @FIELD = 10,
            ... more params...
    END     
IF(@C!= @SC) 
  BEGIN
     exec Stored procedure 
            @FIELD = 17,
            ... more params...
    END 
IF(@W!= @SW)
    BEGIN
     exec Stored procedure 
            @FIELD = 12,
            ... more params...
    END
  --Inserted if statement stop here             
END     
ELSE    
    BEGIN
        SET @ResultMessage = 'Update/Delete Failed. No record found with   ID:'+CONVERT(varchar(50), @ID) 
        SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message' 
        RETURN -1
    END
Set NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

IF you are checking one variable against multiple condition then you would use something like this
Here the block of code where the condition is true will be executed and other blocks will be ignored.

```
IF(@Var1 Condition1)
     BEGIN
      /*Your Code Goes here*/
     END

ELSE IF(@Var1 Condition2)
      BEGIN
        /*Your Code Goes here*/ 
      END 

    ELSE      --<--- Default Task if none of the above is true
     BEGIN
       /*Your Code Goes here*/
     END
```

If you are checking conditions against multiple variables then you would have to go for multiple IF
Statements, Each block of code will be executed independently from other blocks.

```
IF(@Var1 Condition1)
 BEGIN
   /*Your Code Goes here*/
 END


IF(@Var2 Condition1)
 BEGIN
   /*Your Code Goes here*/
 END


IF(@Var3 Condition1)
 BEGIN
   /*Your Code Goes here*/
 END
```

After every IF statement if there are more than one statement being executed you MUST put them in 
 BEGIN..END Block. Anyway it is always best practice to use BEGIN..END blocks

**Update**

Found something in your code some BEGIN END you are missing

```
ELSE IF(@ID IS NOT NULL AND @ID in (SELECT ID FROM Places))   -- Outer Most Block ELSE IF
BEGIN   
     SELECT @MyName = Name ...  
    ...Some stuff....                       
    IF(SOMETHNG_1)         -- IF
                 --BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY               
            UPDATE ....                                                                 
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
            RETURN -1
        END CATCH
                -- END
    ELSE IF(SOMETHNG_2)    -- ELSE IF
                 -- BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            UPDATE ...                                                      
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
            RETURN -1
        END CATCH   
               -- END
    ELSE                  -- ELSE
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRY
                UPDATE ...                                                              
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
                RETURN -1
            END CATCH   
         END             
      --The above works I then insert this below and these if statement become nested----
          IF(@A!= @SA)
            BEGIN
             exec Store procedure 
                    @FIELD = 15,
                    ... more params...
            END                 
        IF(@S!= @SS)
          BEGIN
             exec Store procedure 
                    @FIELD = 10,
                    ... more params...
```

Comment: As stated I am already using `BEGIN..END`, but using that actually throws an error.

Comment: @JackThor using BEGIN..END throws an error ?? it cant be that its something else throwing error. To debug it I would take out all of the code and use PRINT statement in each BEGIN END block something like PRINT 'Block 1' etc etc to check exactly between which blocks your code control is jumping in and out.

Comment: Using the `Begin..END` gives it a red squiggly underline for the last End in the group of If statement that I inserted. And when I hover over it it says `Incorrect syntax near "END". Expecting "CONVERSATION"`

Comment: @JackThor see my update and you are missing some BEGIN END blocks in you MOST OUTER ELSE IF BLOCK I have added them in comments starting with two -- , ignore the commented ELSE and IF ELSE :)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid syntax errors, be sure to always put `BEGIN` and `END` after an `IF` clause, eg:

```
IF (@A!= @SA)
   BEGIN
   --do stuff
   END
IF (@C!= @SC)
   BEGIN
   --do stuff
   END
```

... and so on. This should work as expected. Imagine `BEGIN` and `END` keyword as the opening and closing bracket, respectively.

Comment: I did check the last code block that I posted. It throws an Error.

Comment: Please poste your full statement. Error is elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bit redundant, but no one appeared to have mentioned this as a solution.

As a beginner in SQL I find that when using a `BEGIN` and `END` SSMS usually adds a squiggly line with `incorrect syntax near 'END'` to END, simply because there's no content in between yet. If you're just setting up `BEGIN` and `END` to get started and add the actual query later, then simply add a bogus `PRINT` statement so SSMS stops bothering you.

For example:

```
IF (1=1)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'BOGUS'
END
```

The following will indeed set you on the wrong track, thinking you made a syntax error which in this case just means you still need to add content in between BEGIN and END:

```
IF (1=1)
BEGIN
END
```